# How to make self updating pipeline in concourse

Tags: concourse

I would like to make a pipeline that as first step checks its own configuration and updates itself if needed.

What tool / API should I use for this? Is there a docker image that has this installed for the correct concourse version? What is the advised way to authenticate in concourse from such task?

Comment: are you looking for a pipeline that updates your concourse deployment or updates its configuration file?

Comment: its configuration

Answer (score 3):

naively, it'd be a task which gets the repo the pipeline is committed to, and does a [`fly set-pipeline`](https://concourse.ci/single-page.html#fly-set-pipeline) to update the configuration. However there are a few gotchas here:

- *fly binary.* you'll want `fly` executable to be available to your container which runs this task, and it should be same version of `fly` as the concourse that's being targeted. Probably that means you should download it directly via `curl` from the host.
- *authenticating with the concourse server.* you'll need to provide credentials for `fly` to use -- probably via [parameters](https://concourse.ci/single-page.html#parameters).
- *parameter updates*. if new parameters become needed, you'll need to use some kind of single source for all the parameters that need to be set, and use `--load-vars-from` rather than just `--var`. My group uses Lastpass notes with a bunch of variables saved in them and download via the `lpass` tool, but that gets hard if you use 2FA or similar.
- *moving the server*. You will need the external address of the concourse to be injected as a parameter as well, if you want to be resilient to it changing.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the previous answer suggesting the Fly binary, see the [Fly resource](https://github.com/robdimsdale/concourse-pipeline-resource).

However, having a similar request, I am going to try with the [Pipeline resource](https://github.com/robdimsdale/concourse-pipeline-resource). It seems more specific and has var injection solved directly through parameters.

I still have to try it out, but it seems to me that it would be more efficient to have a single pipeline which updates all pipelines, and not having to insert this job in all of your pipelines.

Also, a specific pipeline should not be concerned with itself, just the source code it builds (or whatever it does). If you want to start a pipeline if its config file changed, this could be done by modifying a triggering resource, e.g. pushing an empty "pipeline changed" commit